# Why am I getting a stale element exception when trying to access the text of an element with Selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to read the text of the elements in a dropdown menu using Selenium, but when I use "element.text" I get a stale element exception. 
This is my code:

```
    list_options = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("select2 results__option")
    for l in list_options:
        if l.text == "DOI":
            l.click()
```

This is the error message I've been getting:

```
if l.text == "DOI":
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 76, in text
return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
(Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 
(255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.1 x86_64)
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to Selenium. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear from your question, are you going to a new page by `click()`ing, then going back to the previous page and trying to go to the next item in a list of previously found elements?

Comment: The clicking is selecting an option from a dropdown menu. It isn't going to a new page or anything.

Comment: Can you please post your select node html, make sure to add atleast one item.

Comment: @Firestarter Even before you face [StaleElementReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640973/staleelementexception-when-iterating-with-python/53646047#53646047) this line of code `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("select2 results__option")` will raise [Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-using-find-element-by-class/53536022#53536022) in the first place

Comment: to make this reproducible, shouldn't you post also the page you're scraping? (and maybe cut out the irrelevant parts) as according to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking on the item, the page is getting refreshed, and the element you have a reference to (stored in a variable) is stale. The page refreshes changes things in such a way that the exact element you stored is no longer on the page. To overcome this, you need to re-assign the drop-down list inside the for loop.

Try the below code.

```
list_options = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.select2.results__option')
for l in range(len(list_options)):
  new_list_options = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.select2.results__option')
  if new_list_options[l].text == "DOI":
      new_list_options[l].click()
```

Comment: `find_elements_by_class_name("select2 results__option")` ???

Comment: @DebanjanB : I know it always good to use css selector instead of class name.However the problem is i guess the page is getting refreshed when OP clicked on drop down item.So that was the solution.I can modify this to css selector.

Comment: I should have been explicit earlier but `find_elements_by_class_name("select2 results__option")` will always raise a [Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-using-find-element-by-class/53536022#53536022)

Comment: Thank you! This worked but I had to change it to finding the elements by class name:

Comment: @Firestarter : Happy to help you.