# StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, html-select, staleelementreferenceexception

I am working on selenium for a website that consists of dropdown menu.

At first, we have the basic codes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = Options()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options= options,executable_path=r'C:\Users...chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('http://.../')
```

Then I am implementing the part to work on the dropdown. My goal is to perform something for each dropdown option.

When I am doing:

```
dropdown = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('DropDownList'))

options = dropdown.options

for index in range(0, len(options) - 1):
    dropdown.select_by_index(index)
    #browser.refresh()
    print(index)
```

It is working just fine.

However, when I am performing some stuff for each dropdown option:

```
dropdown = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('DropDownList'))

options = dropdown.options

for index in range(0, len(options) - 1):
    dropdown.select_by_index(index)
    browser.refresh()
    print(index)
```

Then only the first dropdown option runs and then it shows error:

```
0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-fa7ad153fc9f> in <module>
      5 
      6 for index in range(0, len(options) - 1):
----> 7     dropdown.select_by_index(index)
      8     browser.refresh()
      9     print(index)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py in select_by_index(self, index)
     97            """
     98         match = str(index)
---> 99         for opt in self.options:
    100             if opt.get_attribute("index") == match:
    101                 self._setSelected(opt)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py in options(self)
     45     def options(self):
     46         """Returns a list of all options belonging to this select tag"""
---> 47         return self._el.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'option')
     48 
     49     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in find_elements(self, by, value)
    683 
    684         return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENTS,
--> 685                              {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
    686 
    687     def __hash__(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <span class="pagnCur"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

...implies that the previous reference of the element is now `stale` and the previous element reference is no longer present within the DOM TREE of the webpage.

The common reasons behind this this exception can be either of the following:

- *The element have changed it's position within the HTML DOM.*
- *The element is no longer attached to the DOM TREE.*
- *The webpage on which the element was part of has been refreshed.*
- *The previous instance of element has been refreshed by a JavaScript*.

---

### This usecase

A bit of more details interms of the relevant HTML would have helped us to construct a more canonical answer. However, as per your first code block:

```
dropdown = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('DropDownList'))
options = dropdown.options
for index in range(0, len(options) - 1):
    dropdown.select_by_index(index)
    print(index)
```

It seems selecting the `<option>` elements doesn't result in any changes with in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

But in your second code block:

```
dropdown = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('DropDownList'))
options = dropdown.options
for index in range(0, len(options) - 1):
    dropdown.select_by_index(index)
    browser.refresh()
    print(index)
```

As you are invoking `browser.refresh()` before `print(index)` all the elements within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) gets refreshed and the olden references becomes **stale**.

Hence when you try to `print(index)` [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) complains of [StaleElementReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640973/staleelementexception-when-iterating-with-python/53646047#53646047)

---

### Solution

You don't need the `browser.refresh()` line before `print(index)`. Removing the line `browser.refresh()` will solve your issue.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory/44844879#44844879)

Comment: Hi, actually I need to perform something. The refresh is just an example. Suppose, I need to take screenshots of the webpage for each dropdown option. Even if I dont sun print and just run browser.screenshot() for each iteration, it still gives error

Comment: If you share what you're trying to do do as your "something", we be able to provide a better answer :-)

Comment: Hi, actually what I am doing is a big fat program. It includes some refreshes too.