# TypeError: object of type 'FirefoxWebElement' has no len() error while sending text through send_keys using Selenium Python

Tags: python, list, selenium-webdriver, typeerror, sendkeys

Code trials:

```
lists = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class= 'gradeA']/td[1]")
for list_item in lists:
    print(list_item.text)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='event_name']").send_keys(list_item)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Eventbuizz-t460-ki/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonSelenium/super admin.py", line 31, in <module>
        y.send_keys(list_item)
      File "C:\Users\Eventbuizz-t460-ki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 348, in send_keys
        {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
      File "C:\Users\Eventbuizz-t460-ki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
        for i in range(len(val)):
    TypeError: object of type 'FirefoxWebElement' has no len()
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: In your example you've printed `list_item.text` but in send_keys you're just sending `list_item` which appears to be a web element. If you want to send a string try `.send_keys(list_item.text)`

Comment: when I use  `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='event_name']").send_keys(list_item.text)`
it show error
File "C:\Users\Eventbuizz-t460-ki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 73, in text
    
  File "C:\Users\Eventbuizz-t460-
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <td> stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed


Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: It seems to show your error here `The element reference of <td> stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed`. Does this page refresh when you've enter the details, are you submitting the form within the loop? What do you see happening in the browser?

Comment: no page does not refresh .

Comment: `lists = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class= 'gradeA']/td[1]")
for list_item in lists:
    print(list_item.text)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Events']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Organizer Events']").click()
    time.sleep(8)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='event_name']").send_keys(list_item.text)
`
this is my complete code kindly check

Answer (score 0):

As you are using [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) *`find_elements_by_xpath()`* returns a list of *FirefoxWebElements*.

You can loop through the list:

```
for list_item in lists:
```

And print the *text* within the loop:

```
print(list_item.text)
```

But you can't send any individual *FirefoxWebElement* through *`send_keys()`* within any element.

Hence you see:

```
TypeError: object of type 'FirefoxWebElement' has no len()
```

---

### Solution

Instead of sending the *FirefoxWebElement* through *`send_keys()`* you need to send the element *text* as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='event_name']").send_keys(list_item.text)
```

Comment: when I use driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='event_name']").send_keys(list_item.text) it show error File "C:\Users\Eventbuizz-t460-ki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 73, in text File "C:\Users\Eventbuizz-t460- selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <td> stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: [StaleElementReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62818340/staleelementreferenceexception-message-stale-element-reference-element-is-not/62818861#62818861) sounds to be a different issue all together which needs to be addressed differently. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirements.

Comment: when I use your solution it shows me this error
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='event_name']").send_keys(list_item.text)
  File "C:\Users\Eventbuizz-t460-ki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 73, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Element reference not seen before: db672820-5c96-4ac8-bc09-bffb3439dfaa

Comment: Now you are seeing a _WebDriverException_ which have no relation with the previous error of `'FirefoxWebElement' has no len()`. I strongly feel the specific error of this question have got addressed. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirements.

Comment: hi sir can you please help me current exception that you answered before

Comment: This issue/question is resolved, right? What the issue in accepting the answer?

Comment: my issue is not resolved yet kindly check 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70199223/raise-exception-classmessage-screen-stacktrace-selenium-common-exceptions-we?noredirect=1#comment124093910_70199223

Comment: Then why are you using the line of code I have suggested in this question within your current question?

Comment: Definitely this error of  `TypeError: object of type 'FirefoxWebElement' has no len()` is no more being thrown, how can you say not solved?