# raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Element reference not seen before: f8561f1c-43e9-474a-88f3-22b3e0c813b7

I have multiple list data when I enter this data in to list one by one it gives me this exception. if I enter hard code values like send_keys("100") then it works fine. but when want to send values in run time it gives me an exception.

```
    lists = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class= 'gradeA']/td[1]")
    for list_item in lists:
        print(len(lists))
        print(list_item.text)
    
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Events']").click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Organizer Events']").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(3)
        event_code = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='event_name']").send_keys(list_item.text)
```

Comment: _`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='event_name']").send_keys(list_item.text)`_ : You are using the solution from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70112130/7429447) to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70110348/typeerror-object-of-type-firefoxwebelement-has-no-len-error-while-sending-t). Can you give me a proper feedback please?

Comment: the solution that gives me I have already used. I know it before and thanks for your help kindly help me with this expectation if you know how we solved this. thanks