# How to prevent "State Element Reference" errors in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url="https://fourminutebooks.com/book-summaries/"
driver.get(url)

page_tabs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='post_title w4pl_post_title']")
#html = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"header[class='entry-header page-header']")

length_page_tabs = len(page_tabs)
in_length = len(page_tabs)
for i in range(length_page_tabs):
  ran = random.randint(0,in_length)
  page_tabs[ran].click()
  driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
  time.sleep(10)


  #need to get page source of html and then open it to a new file, extract what I want and add it to the email
```

I am trying to click one of the links, get the html code, email it to myself, and then go back a page and repeat. However after clicking the first random link, the code stops working and instead I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA366.png)

Comment: Please paste the error as text in your question so that it is more readable, can be copied and pasted, etc. Please also include the full stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be very careful, when you put some elements collection to the variable, and going to iterate and perform some actions.

```
page_tabs = driver.find_elements...
```

All the elements in this case are cached, and  each web browser action of navigate to another page, refrech the page, etc. will make all of these cached elements **stale**. This means they bacame like *out-of-date* and not possible to interact them any more.

So, to avoid stale element reference errors, you have to prevent any page reloads, or just refresh the elements every time after the page state has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

### StaleElementReferenceException

[***StaleElementReferenceException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44844879/7429447) is a type of *WebDriverException* which is thrown when a reference to an element have gone *`stale`*, i.e. the element no longer appears on the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of the page.

Some of the possible causes of *StaleElementReferenceException* include:

- You are no longer on the same page, or the page may have refreshed since the element was last located.
- The element may have been removed and re-added to the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes), since it was located. Such as an element being relocated. This can happen typically with a [javascript](https://www.javascript.com/) framework when values are updated and the node is rebuilt.
- Element may have been inside an iframe or another context which was refreshed.

---

### This usecase

In your usecase, you have created a list of [webelement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) i.e. **page_tabs** using the [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

```
page_tabs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='post_title w4pl_post_title']")
```

Next within the loop whenever you invoke click on `page_tabs[ran]` you are redirected to a new page, where the elements within the list `page_tabs` becomes stale and new elements are loaded.

Moving forward when you invoke *`driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")`* you are moving back to the main page where the elements of `page_tabs` were present and they reload again. At this point of time, the list `page_tabs` still continues to hold the webelements of the previous search, which have now become ***stale***. Hence during the second iteration you face ***StaleElementReferenceException***

---

### Solution

In your usecase to avoid *StaleElementReferenceException* as the desired elements are `<A>` tag so instead of saving the elements you can store the *`href`* attributes in a list and invoke *`get(href)`* as follows:

```
driver.get("https://fourminutebooks.com/book-summaries/")
hrefs = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='post_title w4pl_post_title']")))]
for href in hrefs:
    driver.get(href)
    print("Placeholder to perform the desired operations on the respective page")
driver.quit()
```

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [StaleElementException when iterating with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53646047/7429447)
- [Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075477/7429447)
- [StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62818861/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

Use driver.execute_script and javascript. Javascript is never stale because it evaluates right away. In other words, if you select an element with Python and later interact with it, there's a decent chance it won't be there anymore. The only way you can be sure it's still there is to evaluate it as you interact with it and the only way to do that is to stay in the browser context.