# Python selenium script crashes when any delay is added

Tags: python, selenium

I need to add a delay there, but any type of delay makes the code to crash. I need that because this script clicks so fast that the web can not process both and only registers the second one.

```
        """ Returns a pair of web elements corresponding to the first of the morning
        and afternoon bunch of slots*'"""
            
        available_slot_pairs = []
        """ The list of available to book slots """

        available_rows = []

        rows = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fc-event-container")

        for row_index in range(row_offset, len(rows)):
            """ Range is determined by row_offset & number of rows(18)"""

            row = (rows[row_index])

            self.boxcheck(By.CLASS_NAME, "fc-timeline-event")

            slots = row.find_elements_by_class_name("fc-timeline-event")

            slot = slots[0]

            slot6 = slots[6]

            if 's-lc-eq-avail' in slot.get_attribute("class") and 's-lc-eq-avail' in slot6.get_attribute("class"):

                available_slot_pairs.append((slot, slot6))
                    
                available_rows.append(row_index)

        return available_slot_pairs, available_rows                 
    
    def select_seats(self,seat_num):
        """ Clicks the desired available seats and looks for the "SUBMIT TIMES" button to register the selected seats*'"""

        available_slot_pairs, available_rows = self.find_first_available_slots_elements(row_offset=0)
            
        seats_selected = 0     
                            
        for morning_slots_first, afternoon_slots_first in available_slot_pairs:

            morning_slots_first.click()

            #I NEED TO ADD DELAY HERE, BUT NOTHING SEEMS TO WORK <-----------------------------------

            afternoon_slots_first.click()

            seats_selected+=1

            if seats_selected >= seat_num:

                self.fasten(By.ID, 'submit_times')

                self.driver.find_element_by_id('submit_times').click()

                return
```

I can not find any solution to this. I know that after the first click(), if i add this: self.fasten(By.ID, 'submit_times'), the script will wait just enough for the web to process the clicks, any ideas?

Error:
`Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

This error doesn't appear if no delay is added

Comment: It isn't a crash really but [stale element reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640973/staleelementexception-when-iterating-with-python/53646047#53646047)

Comment: means problem solved !

Comment: @SidPro no, it's not solved, my code works fine without delay, but if there's somoe delay that error pops

Comment: @DebanjanB yes, i know, but the element is there, that same code without delay works fine

Comment: @Álvaro d'Ors you tried time.sleep() to give time to web.

Comment: @SidPro, i've tried sleep, time.sleep, webWait, etc

Answer (score 0):

use sleep or use this code for letting the specific part of website to load

```
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ID')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
```

Comment: Didn't worked, the issue isn't the time to find the element, I called again the function that tracks the "slots" are and done.