# Selenium Click the first instance of an element, go back, then click the second instance of the element

Tags: python, selenium

There are many instances of the same class name. I'd like to click the first instance, pull the information I need from that page, go back to the previous page, click the second instance, pull the information I need, and so on until no more instances of the class name exist. Here's what I have so far, but I don't think I'm using the counter correctly.

```
elems = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'XYZabc')
count = 1
data = []

for elem in elems: 
    if count <= 10:
#get text I'm clicking
        data.append(elem.get_attribute('innerText'))
#click link
        link = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'XYZabc').click()
        count = count + 1
#get info from page
        title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/h1').get_attribute('innerText') 
        date = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'publish-date').get_attribute('innerText')
        data.append({
            "Title": title,
            "Date": date
        })
#go back to the first page
    driver.back()
```

Any help/advice would be amazing!
Thanks so much.

Comment: Confirm the url please.

Comment: No URL, it doesn't have an effect on how this loop should operate

Comment: @Micadeli Invoking `back()` would invite [StaleElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53646047/7429447)

Comment: thanks @undetectedSelenium - I'm really just looking to figure out how to structure the loop so that it iterates through class names. Other errors I can troubleshoot later :)

Comment: Honestly _StaleElementException_ isn't any error but a trap ;)

Comment: Just grab driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'XYZabc') everytime you swap pages.